# Can't get Regex group value

Tags: c#, regex

The string I'm trying to parse from looks something like this:

> {"F4q6i9xe":{"Hhgi79M1":"cTZ3W2JG","j0Uszek2":"0"},"a3vSYuq2":{"Kn51uR4Y":"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"}}

And this is my regular expression:

```
Hhgi79M1":"(?<encodeKeyID>.*?)",.*Kn51uR4Y":"(?<encodedBody>.*?)"}
```

And this is the code I'm using in my C# application:

```
string responsePattern = "Hhgi79M1\":\"(?<encodeKeyID>.*?)\",.*Kn51uR4Y\":\"(?<encodedBody>.*?)\"}";
if (Regex.IsMatch(body, responsePattern))
{
    var match = Regex.Match(body, responsePattern);
    string encodeKeyID = match.Groups["encodeKeyID"].Value;
    string encodedBody = match.Groups["encodedBody"].Value;
```

Now it works, but it doesn't get the value of "encodedBody". I tested my expression with the data on https://regex101.com/ and it seems to work fine on there. However, when getting the value in my program it's just an empty string.

Comment: What's expected result?

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a JSON parser.

Comment: @SLaks Got any ideas for a decent one? I don't wanna be deserializing.

Comment: Have you seen JSON.net?

Comment: @Shafizadeh Expected result is that it gets the value of that really long base64 string you can see.

Comment: Try `Regex.Match(body, responsePattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)`

Comment: @JamesBuck I did some debugging with breakpoints. It's getting the value, it just won't display it in a messagebox prompt.

Comment: Your code works fine as is.  Maybe you have a problem, as you suggested, with the message box.  I got your code to match both named groups.  Maybe you have a max limit in your message box

Comment: When you have a JSON and you use a regex with `.*?` or `.*`, you'd better discard the regex at all. JSON is a tree like thing, and `.*` / `.*?` will skip over objects matching what-not. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: If you really need to parse Json text with a regular expression then I suggest do not use `.*` as it may collect more than you intended. For example if the input string had two occurrences of `Kn51uR4Y`. For the start of your regular expression I much prefer the more restrictive `Hhgi79M1":"(?<encodeKeyID>[^"]*?)",.*` as it will only gather character between the string quote characters. The same style can be used instead of the other `.*` segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense the issue is that your body string is not escaped properly, as your pattern works fine in the following code:

```
            string body = "{\"F4q6i9xe\":{\"Hhgi79M1\":\"cTZ3W2JG\",\"j0Uszek2\":\"0\"},\"a3vSYuq2\":{\"Kn51uR4Y\":\"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\"}}\n" +
"";
            string responsePattern = "Hhgi79M1\":\"(?<encodeKeyID>.*?)\",.*Kn51uR4Y\":\"(?<encodedBody>.*?)\"}";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(body, responsePattern))
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(body, responsePattern);
                string encodeKeyID = match.Groups["encodeKeyID"].Value;
                string encodedBody = match.Groups["encodedBody"].Value;
                string msg = String.Format("encodeKeyID: {0}\nencodedBody: {1}", encodeKeyID, encodedBody);
                //show in message box
                MessageBox.Show(msg, "Pattern Match Result");
            }
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
string sTarget = @"
{""F4q6i9xe"":{""Hhgi79M1"":""cTZ3W2JG"",""j0Uszek2"":""0""},""a3vSYuq2"":{""Kn51uR4Y"":""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""}}
";

Regex responseRx = new Regex(@"Hhgi79M1"":""(?<encodeKeyID>.*?)"",.*Kn51uR4Y"":""(?<encodedBody>.*?)""}");
Match responseMatch = responseRx.Match(sTarget);
if (responseMatch.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}", responseMatch.Groups["encodeKeyID"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Body = {0}", responseMatch.Groups["encodedBody"].Value);
}
```

Output

```
ID = cTZ3W2JG
Body = c6QUklQzv+kRLnmvS0zsheqDsRCXbWFVpYhq2rsElKyFQnla01E6P3qQ26b+xWSrscFJCi2qs
h6WjJKSW5FN9EwxRAWc3rfyToaEhRngI2WPu3W\/b1\/hkkS2tEEk7LEpS2ItxLYKjEQGneO5E9rcGzb
tfSOikdIjhxpD5m9HsKayo2ZSc2EYd\/cN9yfYrNfLOCx+xeGqGcPmmImAzOZM0Q1IXIDQZ5r70vUS1a
UOMOFnN1fVxmQ8ISofEKNEpHFfwWW9QUl9eVDgpQ2HES13s20kvVH2FOlE5uahIJBnyTLWYzViAWYyX1
3VK2PgrQcZ0oLuV84bSbjHGZf+JAjvImuyYhkKDhtTWAGkQ8LZ6r07duo71Gbz3glOUZZyz+FFiH5Krw
afBpzGhRlI8El6lLZASN9Z5iZNTKs+sOti1fzsuOBzUXEjFURJGa93GMqPC+OyTw6YxKvgapz7go1XL7
EAf50UXpMHd9xAJzsuIb6\/lB\/6v+XjD70wc74D2OosxtR6DIbQj3gbaBUBABQsJHQZLNnHWqikh+HL
CASVbkqw6YPm5NecGaOQxonDkh3ZVQSF15WCEsgNdoWG94OuLF8DSw1t1Kt8sMFkvBJgB7LJS3pAw\/T
cg\/rvR5qwZ\/n31rtOzaJgCdVc6XeIK6Rttj4KvNtgtTwkJIjb97FgIS0CXrR0UCp3BsuLwQg3CRTnj
QqsjGgJeinLXX2lq6vNOkxRzgXlWnap96kheYj7sIE\/IxbJJWEIInMbH9HU\/w0bS0MtIgofpIQAZ\/
m6XKhu9LpPZBgsBf9KX5chUPeuRfs3MfHFzPYPlCCd2dkE8BHKOTmfS3okqhkzIZvFN3Ni+7enktFdgf
pQ0toQbjhpn\/TszP34pBaIy77me+GvePNO5bAFECLWSpGvsmW16rLCP0H+xIS\/lNf9hK98jQqGU7eq
pQdai7WFie2yN75Up7MrgBMp5w9Z5C7qpG2iYGiqynpqTCEnfQ3IZumbL+YvGTiuI2c320MGjKzOdO45
MIU5fxUNZQSIfCSyIq5G\/XGIeXCG3KETyKDZygXUTgEWbJWNTADE0AhXvP7HMtsuvstyuHvlTZGcfKS
4oLnDPFiV1ndIV7+W74Ytv9bAdDIVl36xTzA2PV6waqXBfSPUCTx3jVrAeXcHGFjZtxbk3pFmuqPqgVc
xeX\/aDbK0NHkR6phQcFEREBjfdCOLAAbCkWiRF0JAA==
```

Comment: Yeah my method was working anyway, it just wouldn't appear in a message box. Same with your method.

Comment: My method is a console app. But, there is no use doing _match_ twice. So, there is the difference.